# Modify value of duplicated rows before removing duplicates

Tags: r, duplicates, data-manipulation

I'm trying to modify table in R. I've got table with few thousands of rows and I want to remove duplicate rows (Package) and modify in and out date of those rows (before removing them). The goal is to take earlier IN-DATE and older OUT-DATE of duplicated rows.

```
Package;IN-DATE;OUT-DATE  
AMFU12;2023-01-30;2023-01-30
AXIU18;2023-01-11;2023-01-11
FANU45;2022-11-11;2023-01-23
FANU45;2022-11-11;2023-01-23
QIBU55;2023-01-11;2023-01-23
QIBU55;2023-01-23;2023-01-30
```

On the end, I want to get table with unique Package column and modified in and out date, like below:

```
Package; IN-DATE    ;OUT-DATE  
AMFU12 ; 2023-01-30 ;2023-01-30
AXIU18 ; 2023-01-11 ;2023-01-11
FANU45 ; 2022-11-11 ;2023-01-23
QIBU55 ; 2023-01-11 ;2023-01-30
```

At this moment I've only reached to remove all duplicated rows. I don't know how to include duplicated rows with modified in and out date.

```
duplicates <- 
  packages %>% 
  group_by(Package) %>%
  mutate(duplicate = n()) %>%
  filter(duplicate > 1) %>%
  select(-duplicate)
```

I would appreciate your suggestions in this case. Maybe you can find different approach in this issue.

Comment: I believe that I found the solution by myself
```solution <- 
   packages %>%
   group_by(Package) %>% 
   summarise(d.in=min(IN.DATE) ,out=max(OUT.DATE))```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal in R by using the dplyr package to remove duplicate rows based on the 'Package' column and then modify the 'IN-DATE' and 'OUT-DATE' columns to retain the earliest 'IN-DATE' and the latest 'OUT-DATE' for each unique 'Package'. Here's how you can do it:

```
# Sample data with corrected column names
data <- data.frame(
  Package = c("AMFU12", "AXIU18", "FANU45", "FANU45", "QIBU55", "QIBU55"),
  IN_DATE = as.Date(c("2023-01-30", "2023-01-11", "2022-11-11", "2022-11-11", "2023-01-11", "2023-01-23")),
  OUT_DATE = as.Date(c("2023-01-30", "2023-01-11", "2023-01-23", "2023-01-23", "2023-01-23", "2023-01-30"))
)

library(dplyr)

# Group by Package, retain earliest IN_DATE and latest OUT_DATE
result <- data %>%
  group_by(Package) %>%
  summarize(
    IN_DATE = min(IN_DATE),
    OUT_DATE = max(OUT_DATE)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

# Print the result
print(result)
```

rsults will be as

```
Package IN_DATE    OUT_DATE  
  <chr>   <date>     <date>    
1 AMFU12  2023-01-30 2023-01-30
2 AXIU18  2023-01-11 2023-01-11
3 FANU45  2022-11-11 2023-01-23
4 QIBU55  2023-01-11 2023-01-30
```